# How to get pagination in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, pagination

In controller:

```
function show($feast_id)
{
    $feastMenu = Feast::find($feast_id);
    $feastMenu->load('images', 'menu', 'users');
    $feastMenu->chef->load('chefMeta');
    $feastMenu = $feastMenu->toArray();
    return view('feasts.showFeastMenu', compact('feastMenu'));
}

in views

@foreach($feastMenu['menu'] as $k => $menu)

Menu“{{$feastMenu['name']}}”({{count($feastMenu['menu'])}} course meal)

{{$menu['name']}}

@foreach($menu['menu_items'] as $item)

{{$item['name']}}
    {{$item['description']}}
@endforeach

@endforeach
```

How can I set pagination into this please suggest in laravel I am using laravel 5. I have used relation into the controller and pass those `toArray`

Comment: Have you tried anything? Doesn't seem so.. anyway, here's a simple google search:  https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/pagination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things i have questions about... but first you should really take a look at the documentation https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/pagination it does a really good job explaining how to do what you want...

Anyways to answer you question i would do it this way... (note how i changed the views due to the returning collection instead of array). Also this will be under the assumption that you are using bootstrap.. if you are not you will need to look over the documentation to see how to add the pagination links

Controller:

```
function show($feast_id)
{
    $feastMenu = Feast::find($feast_id)->simplePaginate(5);
    $feastMenu->load('images', 'menu', 'users');
    $feastMenu->chef->load('chefMeta');
    return view('feasts.showFeastMenu', compact('feastMenu'));
}
```

View:

```
@foreach($feastMenu->menu as $k => $menu)

Menu“{{$feastMenu->name}}”({{$feastMenu->menu->count())}} course meal)

{{$menu->name}}

@foreach($menu->menu_items as $item)

{{$item->name}}
    {{$item->description}}
@endforeach

@endforeach

{{ $feastMenu->links() }}
```